# Create query in Access to have new ID in each item

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access 2010:

```
PartID  PartName
C0001   CHAIR
S0001   SOFA
S0002   SOFA
S0003   SOFA
DT0001  DINNING TABLE
DT0002  DINNING TABLE
```

I'd like to create a query to have:

```
PartID  PartName
C0002   CHAIR
S0004   SOFA
DT0003  DINNING TABLE
```

Can somebody show me the link or how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to insert those records into the first table or?

Comment: No. I just want the new ID of each item in a new query. All records in the first table remain unchanged.

Comment: Is this for a job or a homework assignment?  Because if it's for a job, you should change the design of your table.

Comment: Is for homework. Thanks a lot, Johny!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been tested and works.

```
SELECT 
LEFT([PartID], InStr([PartID], "0")-1) & RIGHT(MAX(CINT(RIGHT([PartID],4)))+10001,4) AS NPartId, tblParts.PartName
FROM tblParts
GROUP BY tblParts.PartName, LEFT([PartID], InStr([PartID], "0")-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with this query:

```
SELECT 
Tabel1.PartName
, RIGHT(MAX(CINT(RIGHT([PartID],4)))+10001,4) AS NewId
FROM Tabel1
GROUP BY Tabel1.PartName
```

A lookuptable with the PartName and the prefixes can be usefull to add the prefix to the new ID.